# Pros and cons of embedded Cocoa Touch Frameworks?

Tags: swift, xcode6, cocoa-touch

I am using Swift, Xcode 6. Is there any good reasons to separate common code between watch app and main app into a separate Cocoa Touch Framework (embedded into the project)? By code I mean core data models, maybe some helper extensions etc. I have not intension to use this framework in other projects. Instead of creating framework, I can just add files to both targets.

Also, is there any problems with swift, framework versions that I can run into when creating new releases of the app?